# string contains an invalid character - Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I'm building a dynamic form and after it is created, I'm trying to rename the name="" attribute of the clone to something else (I'll use these names to get the data of the form into php).

There is a counter (cgCnt) which counts the total number of form fields. The part of my code looks like this

```
var allInputs = cpInCg[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
allInputs[0].setAttribute(name, "cg"+cgCnt+"cpName[]");       // cgCnt is the counter
```

However this gives an error in firebug saying "Invalid character in the string".

To make sure, I've tried the following

```
var allInputs = cpInCg[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
var test = "cg"+cgCnt+"cpName[]";
alert(test);
allInputs[0].setAttribute(name, test);
```

This gives me the same error, but the alert(test) pops up the string with the right value.

I also tried

```
var allInputs = cpInCg[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
var test = "cg"+cgCnt+"cpName[]";
test = test.toString();
alert(test);
allInputs[0].setAttribute(name, test);
```

I thought the "[]" in the string might be the reason (as I need them to be an array) and so tried without them. But still no solution.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks

Comment: It should be `setAttribute('name', ...)`, first argument is string

Comment: This can happen if `allInputs[0]` is not valid `input` element, can you please alert `allInputs[0]` ?

Comment: Oops. I was looking at the wrong place to debug it. putting name in single quotes worked. Thanks